# How to avoid using "this" in Javascript prototypes

Tags: javascript, this, prototypal-inheritance

Here's my javascript object, I would like to know how to avoid using "this" so many times in prototype. I know there is lot of theory and links for prototypal inhericance and this has probably been answered already, but as I haven't been able to make all ends meet, I thought this may be worth another question.

```
function shape(smth) {
    this.a = smth
    this.b = 2
    this.c = 3
}

shape.prototype.doCalculus = function () {
    return this.a * this.b + this.c - (2 * (this.b + this.c) + this.a);
}

module.exports = shape
```

Comment: There is no implicit way to refer to properties of the context object. The best you can do is the `with` statement, but it's got all sorts of problems and is best avoided.

Comment: If you want public members of an object, they MUST be referenced from the `this` pointer.  That's how OO works in Javascript.  No alternative.  If you have lots of references to the same variable within a function, you can temporarily put it in a local variable just to save some reference logic.

Comment: @jfriend00, I'd be happy to accept this as an answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want public members of an object, they MUST be referenced from the `this` pointer. That's how OO works in Javascript. No alternative.

If you have lots of references to the same variable within a function, you can temporarily put it in a local variable just to save some reference logic (same as with any multiple step reference), but you will still have to initially retrieve using `this.varName`.

---

There is a scheme that uses "private" member variables in a constructor closure and does not use the prototype that can be used in some situations and this allows you to refer to the variables directly without this use of `this`:

```
function shape(smth) {
    var a = smth,
        b = 2,
        c = 3;

    this.doCalculus = function() {
        return a * b + c - (2 * (b + c) + a);
    }
}

module.exports = shape
```

For object types where you create lots of instances, this may consume a bit more memory because methods are not stored on a shared prototype, but are created separately for each instance.  There are those who argue the difference in memory consumption is immaterial in most uses.

Comment: How are you supposed to use the `function shape` code? I've tried that snippet wrapped in a `<script type="module">...</script>` in a HTML page, with a `window.shape = shape;` added at end of the script - and when I load the page, and type `shape()` in the Firefox 115 JS Debugger, I get "Uncaught TypeError: this is undefined"?

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to avoid using `this` in the constructor, by using `Object.create` to create the prototype chain, then declaring your properties directly on the resulting object.

```
function Shape(smth) {
  var shape = Object.create(Shape.prototype);

  shape.a = smth;
  shape.b = 2;
  shape.c = 3;

  return shape;
}
```

This removes the need for `this` in your `Shape` function, meaning that we no longer need to call it with `new` either.

```
new Shape(1); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, __proto__: Shape.prototype }
Shape(1);     // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, __proto__: Shape.prototype }
```

However, you'll still need to use `this` inside your prototype methods to refer to the correct instance.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid "this", you can do it like this:

```
const shape = smth => {
      let a = smth,
          b = 2,
          c = 3;
      return {
        doCalculus: () => a * b + c - (2 * (b + c) + a)
      }
    }

    console.log(shape(2).doCalculus()); // -5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid `this` like this:

```
function Shape(smth) {
    return {"a": smth, "b": 2, "c": 3 };
}
```

But a caveat I need to add is the returned object doesn't seem to play well with adding methods using `Shape.prototype.methodname`

So as far as I can work out, for the original example you would need to do:

```
function Shape(smth) {
    return {"a": smth, 
            "b": 2, 
            "c": 3,
            doCalculus: function () {
                return this.a * this.b + this.c - (2 * (this.b + this.c) + this.a);
            }
    }
```

So you've still ended up with this(es), and you've lost the advantages of separating methods under `prototype`. I've also tried to get jslint to pass my code without ticking the "Tolerate... this" box, but I've come to the conclusion it's much better to just use `this`. Everyone except Douglas Crockford seems to accept it as an integral part of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [with statement,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) although *it is highly unrecommended* and will not work in [strict mode.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

```js
function Shape(smth) {
    this.a = smth;
    this.b = 2;
    this.c = 3;
}

Shape.prototype.doCalculus = function () {
    with(this) {
        return a * b + c - (2 * (b + c) + a);
    }
};

console.log(new Shape(5).doCalculus());
```